# How to use RandomForest in Spark Pipeline

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, pipeline, random-forest, apache-spark-ml

I want to tunning my model with grid search and cross validation with spark. In the spark, it must put the base model in a pipeline, the [office demo of pipeline](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-guide.html#example-model-selection-via-cross-validation) use the `LogistictRegression` as an base model, which can be new as an object. However, the `RandomForest` model cannot be **new** by client code, so it seems not be able to use `RandomForest` in the pipeline api. I don't want to recreate an wheel, so can anybody give some advice? 
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> However, the RandomForest model cannot be new by client code, so it seems not be able to use RandomForest in the pipeline api.

Well, that is true but you simply trying to use a wrong class. Instead of `mllib.tree.RandomForest` you should use `ml.classification.RandomForestClassifier`. Here is an example based on [the one from MLlib docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-ensembles.html#classification).

```scala
import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.RandomForestClassifier
import org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StringIndexer
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector
import org.apache.spark.mllib.util.MLUtils
import sqlContext.implicits._ 

case class Record(category: String, features: Vector)

val data = MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile(sc, "data/mllib/sample_libsvm_data.txt")
val splits = data.randomSplit(Array(0.7, 0.3))
val (trainData, testData) = (splits(0), splits(1))

val trainDF = trainData.map(lp => Record(lp.label.toString, lp.features)).toDF
val testDF = testData.map(lp => Record(lp.label.toString, lp.features)).toDF

val indexer = new StringIndexer()
  .setInputCol("category")
  .setOutputCol("label")

val rf  = new RandomForestClassifier()
    .setNumTrees(3)
    .setFeatureSubsetStrategy("auto")
    .setImpurity("gini")
    .setMaxDepth(4)
    .setMaxBins(32)

val pipeline = new Pipeline()
    .setStages(Array(indexer, rf))

val model = pipeline.fit(trainDF)

model.transform(testDF)
```

There is one thing I couldn't figure out here. As far as I can tell it should be possible to use labels extracted from `LabeledPoints` directly, but for some reason it doesn't work and `pipeline.fit` raises `IllegalArgumentExcetion`:

> RandomForestClassifier was given input with invalid label column label, without the number of classes specified.

Hence the ugly trick with `StringIndexer`. After applying we get required attributes (`{"vals":["1.0","0.0"],"type":"nominal","name":"label"}`) but some classes in `ml` seem to work just fine without it.

Comment: RandomForestClassifier is new feature in spark v1.4,  but my envrionment now is 1.3, I have to wait the end of this month for my spark cluster to update to 1.4 :-(

Comment: With randomforest I've got the output, but I can't figure out how to read it:
`(1.0 -> prediction=0.0,  prob=[0.90,0.08]`
`(0.0 -> prediction=1.0,  prob=[0.01,0.88]`
It looks like prediction here is just an index of the highest probability value. Which means I have to look at my classes to figure out what the actual class. The problem is that without "ugly hack" it's not possible to know these classes. Is it how that's suppose to work or did I missed anything?

Comment: It is expected. ML expects 0 based labels (0.0, 1.0, 2.0) and predictions and probabilities reflect that.

Comment: 0-based is clear. The problem is different. I have 10 classes - from 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, up to 9.0. RandomForest gives me some prediction like this: `(4.0 -> prediction=7.0`, `9.0 -> prediction=3.0`, `2.0 -> prediction=4.0`, `8.0 -> prediction=8.0`. According to the docs, predicted is "predicted label", which doesn't look like that. But! Having map of classes like I've got from StringIndexer (`{"ml_attr":{"vals":["1.0","7.0","3.0","9.0","2.0","6.0","0.0","4.0","8.0","5.0"],"type":"nominal","name":"indexedLabel"}}`) and apply "prediction" just as index to the map I will get correct predictions!

Comment: Yes, thats correct. I am afraid that predicted label means output from `StringIndexer` not some-original-string and this is a correct / expected behavior. In 1.6.0 there is `IndexToString` transformer which can be used for inverse mapping.