# Run 3000+ Random Forest Models By Group Using Spark MLlib Scala API

Tags: r, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I am trying to build random forest models by group(School_ID, more than 3 thousands) on a large model input csv file using Spark Scala API. Each of the group contains about 3000-4000 records. The resources I have at disposal are 20-30 aws m3.2xlarge instances.

In R, I can construct models by group and save them to a list like this-

```
library(dplyr);library(randomForest);
    Rf_model <- train %>% group_by(School_ID) %>% 
                do(school= randomForest(formula=Rf_formula, data=., importance = TRUE))
```

The list can be stored somewhere and I can call them when I need to use them like below -

```
save(Rf_model.school,file=paste0(Modelpath,"Rf_model.dat"))
load(file=paste0(Modelpath,"Rf_model.dat"))
pred <-  predict(Rf_model.school$school[school_index][[1]], newdata=test)
```

I was wondering how to do that in Spark, whether or not I need to split the data by group first and how to do it efficiently if it's necessary.

I was able to split up the file by School_ID based on the below code but it seems it creates one individual job to subset for each iteration and takes a long time to finish the jobs. Is there a way to do it in one pass?

```
model_input.cache()

val schools = model_input.select("School_ID").distinct.collect.flatMap(_.toSeq)
val bySchoolArray = schools.map(School_ID => model_input.where($"School_ID" <=> School_ID))

for( i <- 0 to programs.length - 1 ){
  bySchoolArray(i).
    write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").
    option("header", "true").
    save("model_input_bySchool/model_input_"+ schools(i))
}
```

Source:
[How can I split a dataframe into dataframes with same column values in SCALA and SPARK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31669308/how-can-i-split-a-dataframe-into-dataframes-with-same-column-values-in-scala-and)

**Edit 8/24/2015** 
I'm trying to convert my dataframe into a format that is accepted by the random forest model. I'm following the instruction on this thread 
[How to create correct data frame for classification in Spark ML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31028806/how-to-create-correct-data-frame-for-classification-in-spark-ml)

Basically, I create a new variable "label" and store my class in Double. Then I combine all my features using VectorAssembler function and transform my input data as follows-

```
val assembler = new VectorAssembler().
  setInputCols(Array("COL1", "COL2", "COL3")).
  setOutputCol("features")

val model_input = assembler.transform(model_input_raw).
  select("SCHOOL_ID", "label", "features")
```

Partial error message(let me know if you need the complete log message) -

> scala.MatchError: StringType (of class
>   org.apache.spark.sql.types.StringType$)
>           at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler$$anonfun$2.apply(VectorAssembler.scala:57)

This is resolved after converting all the variables to numeric types.

**Edit 8/25/2015**
The ml model doesn't accept the label I coded manually so I need to use StringIndexer to go around the problem as indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32108887/how-to-use-randomforest-in-spark-pipeline). According to the [official documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#stringindexer), the most frequent label gets 0. It causes inconsistent labels across School_ID. I was wondering if there's a way to create the labels without resetting the order of the values.

```
val indexer = new StringIndexer().
  setInputCol("label_orig").
  setOutputCol("label")
```

Any suggestions or directions would be helpful and feel free to raise any questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you already have separate data frame for each school there is not much to be done here. Since you data frames I assume you want to use `ml.classification.RandomForestClassifier`. If so you can try something like this:

1. Extract pipeline logic. Adjust `RandomForestClassifier` parameters and transformers according to your requirements

   ```
   import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
   import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.RandomForestClassifier
   import org.apache.spark.ml.{Pipeline, PipelineModel}

   def trainModel(df: DataFrame): PipelineModel = {
      val rf  = new RandomForestClassifier()
      val pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(Array(rf))
      pipeline.fit(df)
   }
   ```
2. Train models on each subset

   ```
   val bySchoolArrayModels = bySchoolArray.map(df => trainModel(df))
   ```
3. Save models

   ```
   import java.io._

   def saveModel(name: String, model: PipelineModel) = {
     val oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(s"/some/path/$name"))
     oos.writeObject(model)
     oos.close
   }

   schools.zip(bySchoolArrayModels).foreach{
     case (name, model) => saveModel(name, Model)
   }
   ```
4. **Optional**: Since individual subsets are rather small you can try an approach similar to the one I've describe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31916657/1560062) to submit multiple tasks at the same time.
5. If you use `mllib.tree.model.RandomForestModel` you can omit 3. and use  `model.save` directly. Since there seem to be some problems with deserialization ([How to deserialize Pipeline model in spark.ml?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29644507/1560062) - as far as I can tell it works just fine but better safe than sorry, I guess) it could be a preferred approach.

**Edit**

According to [the official documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#vectorassembler):

> `VectorAssembler` accepts the following input column types: all numeric types, boolean type, and vector type.

Since error indicates your column is a `String` you should transform it first, for example using [`StringIndexer`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#stringindexer).

Comment: Thank you! This is helpful! I am trying to convert my dataframe into the format that is accepted by the random forest model by creating a variable "label" with type Double and combining the features using VectorAssembler function. However, the scala console indicates MatchError: StringType. Do you know what I did wrong here. I'm providing more detailed information in the post.

Comment: Thanks again! The error went away after I converted all the variables to numeric types.

Comment: You're welcome and if you find it helpful you can always upvote the answer :)

Comment: I would love to! I have a follow-up question for StringIndexer. Please see an edit.

Comment: Thanks :) I think this one deserves a separate question. I've been trying to figure out something similar to avoid re-encoding but the only option I found is [to use developers API directly to set column metadata](https://gist.github.com/zero323/57f5bf94be02caa39994) and I doubt it is a good idea.